# Need to play audio into a call

Tags: android

If my application records some audio with MediaRecorder, is it possible to play the recorded audio file into a call that was started with ACTION_CALL or ACTION_DIAL?

I see that I can start calls from an application but is there a way for my application to know that the call was answered? At this point I would like to play a file of audio into the call. Then, is there a way for me to end the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not yet possible on Android. See this [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2117#c226).

You can record your voice from microphone, but you can not record the sound of the other party.

Comment: Thanks. Just a clarification. I am wondering if I can play audio into a call, not record audio from a call. Automated telemarketers can do it. They make a call, and then play a message to you.

Comment: same thing im trying to achieve, and came to this post, as you said it is not possible on Android, i want to know is it possible in android version 2.3.3 or later ??

Comment: I don't have a device with 2.3.3 or later, so I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

android.intent.action.ANSWER may be what you are looking for, or possibly PhoneStateIntentReceiver.