# In Android, how can I play mp3 through telephony and not allow to play through wired headset or bluetooth headset even if it is plugged in?

Tags: android, telephony, android-audiomanager

1. I would like to play a music media (e.g. mp3) file in a telephony way instead of speaker way. How can I do it?
2. When a wired headset or bluetooth headset plugs in, I want to keep it playing through telephony still, i.e. just leave the plugged in headset having no sound. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible using the SDK AFAIK. See [Need to play audio into a call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005259/need-to-play-audio-into-a-call) and the bugzilla entry that it links to for additional information.