# How to play an audio format into a call in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to play an audio file into a call in android phones like telemarketing calls, is it possible in android's current version. This question was asked 
[Need to play audio into a call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005259/need-to-play-audio-into-a-call) 
two years back, and the answer is NO. Can anyone confirm current version of android having this feature or not?

Answer (score 0):

Android still (as of Jellybean MR1) doesn't provide an API for it. I doubt that it will do so in the future either, but you never know.

Some hardware platforms used in current Android phones do have support for this functionality, but as an app developer there's no way for you to take advantage of this.

TL;DR: The answer is still "No, it's not possible".